# Filter items that have common properties in JS

Tags: javascript

I have wizard that asks several predefined questions to find-out user needs. at the end it must offer some items based on user answers. all of available items have some properties in common and one or two specific properties. what is the best way or algorithm to do this in JavaScript?

e.g:

**Item 1 Properties:**

- Name
- Weight
- Color
- Size

**Item 2 Properties:**

- Name
- Size
- Weight

**Item 3 Properties:**

- Name
- Color
- Size

**We ask these questions first:**

1. Do you want name to be shown? **-Yes** -No
2. Does size matter?             -Yes **-No**
3. Does it have to be colored?   **-Yes** -No

Finally system should show Item 1 and 2 as available choices.

Comment: I think your question is too vague. Can you give an example of question? What is the relationship between the items and the questions? What part of the code do you really need? Do you use Jquery?

Comment: The simple way is use `for` loop the find out what you needs.

Comment: @Gnucki It doesn't matter if I code it using jQuery or plain JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample page. I note some `TODO` where you should add some code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Hello!</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            'use strict';

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var items = {
                    ferrari: {
                        color: 'red',
                    },
                    bmw: {
                        color: 'black',
                        size: 4
                    }
                };

                $('#select-item').click(function(event) {
                    // Compute the scores for each item.
                    var answers = $(this).parents('form').serializeArray(),
                        itemScores = {}
                    ;

                    for (var key in items) {
                        itemScores[key] = 0;

                        for (var property in items[key]) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
                                var questionNumber = answers[j].name.substr('answers['.length, 1),
                                    question = $('#question' + questionNumber),
                                    weights = question.data('weights') || {}
                                ;

                                // TODO: do a special calculation for each property
                                // switch (property) { case 'color': ... break; case 'size': ... break; }
                                itemScores[key] += weights[property] || 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Display the list of results
                    // TODO: display only the items with the best scores.
                    var list = $(document.createElement('ul'));

                    for (var key in itemScores) {
                        var item = $(document.createElement('li'));

                        item.text(key + ': ' + itemScores[key]);
                        list.append(item);
                    }

                    $('#results').html(list);

                    // Prevent the default behaviour of the form.
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="answers[0]">Do you want name to be shown?</label>
                    <input id="question0" name="answers[0]" type="checkbox" value=1 />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="answers[1]">Does size matter?</label>
                    <input id="question1" name="answers[1]" type="checkbox" value=1 data-weights='{"size":2}' />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="answers[2]">Does it have to be colored?</label>
                    <input id="question2" name="answers[2]" type="checkbox" value=1 data-weights='{"color":1}' />
                </li>
                <input id="select-item" type="submit" />
            </ul>
        </form>

        <div id="results">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to do that kind of algorithm on the server side (with NodeJS) I did a tutorial in the documentation of the full-stack framework [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf) that do something like that. Here is the direct link to the [tutorial](https://github.com/gnodi/danf/blob/master/doc/test/index.md) (I warn you that it may be a little hard for a beginner).